# broken link when using <a href=""> to link to other html file in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 2 html in my google script and trying to create a link from one.html to two.html . When i load one.html, i can see the link of two.html. I can right-click and choose "open link in new tab" and it will works just fine. But if i click the link directly, google script refuses it. I got broken link error : script.google.com refused to connect.

I can copy/paste the url so the generated url is definetely correct but i can't link by clicking the <a href="">.

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

**Code.gs**

```
function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}

function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log( Utilities.jsonStringify(e) );
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('one').evaluate();
  }
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate();
}
```

**one.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>ONE</h1>
    <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=two'> two.html</a>
    <p><?=url?>?page=two</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**two.html** (just an empty page)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>TWO</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work if you change to double quotes? `<a href="<?=url?>?page=two">`

Comment: Still the same. I got : script.google.com refused to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `target="_top"` to the a tag

I think it relates to iframe problem of web apps